# Set emacs -nw as default editor

Tags: default-programs, emacs, update-alternatives

When editing files like `sudoers`, I want to use emacs instead of nano. So I ran this command

```
sudo update-alternatives --config editor
```

And I selected emacs. The only issue is I like emacs in no window mode (the -nw flag) and I've aliased emacs as `emacs='emacs -nw'` so that I can use no window mode in normal use, but I don't know how to get my default editor to be in no window mode.

In other words, I need to get the command `sudo visudo` and similar commands that open up editors to open the file with `emacs -nw`. How can I do this? I'm on Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: This is unrelated, but if you're intending to use `emacs -nw' as your default terminal editor, you may want to look into emacsclient and running emacs as a daemon. Otherwise, I would think that it would be far too slow to startup. With an emacs server, it's practically instant startup, and not difficult to set up.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Create a script that starts emacs with -nw flag, e.g. /usr/local/bin/emacs-nw.

```
#!/bin/sh

emacs -nw "$@"
```

Install it with update-alternatives --install.

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/editor editor /usr/local/bin/emacs-nw 2
```

Configure editor to be your new script.

```
sudo update-alternatives --set editor /usr/local/bin/emacs-nw
```

Comment: For those who don't use update-alternatives featured systems, `chmod +x /usr/local/bin/emacs-nw` and `export EDITOR='emacs-nw'` in `.bashrc` do the trick.

Comment: Simply updating the EDITOR shell variable to call `emacs -nw` is more traditional and doesn't involve all this weird file creation for such a simple task. Why is this better?

Comment: > Why is this better?

In my case because, `-nw` or any other flags are ignored, when editor is invoked from midnight commander (`use internal editor` flag in `mc` is set to `false` so that `F4` invokes `$EDITOR`)

Answer (score 10):

Add the following to your `~/.bashrc` file (or the config file for your shell if it is not Bash).

`export EDITOR="emacs -nw"`

This should set (and export) an env variable setting your default editor as Emacs in non-graphical mode.

Comment: After setting `EDITOR` how would you open Emacs in graphical mode?

Comment: @Manolete you can use `command emacs`, this will run Emacs without aliases and such. Of course you can also `unalias emacs` for a session.

Comment: @Manolete Actually launching emacs with `emacs` at the command line or clicking on it's icon will still launch the graphical form. The command above in my post just sets the EDITOR enviromental variable to "emacs -nw" it actually does not create an alias. It just tells the shell that your preferred editor is emacs -nw. `emacs` will still launch the graphical form.

Answer (score 2):

I have following setting in my `~/.bashrc`

```
export EDITOR="emacsclient -t -a=\"\""
```

This will first try to connect emacs daemon server if it is already started, otherwise start daemon server first then connect again.

Similarly, I have following setting in my `~/.gitconfig`

```
[core]
    editor = emacsclient -t -a=\\\"\\\"
```